# How to transfer multiple data to different acitivity

Tags: java, android

I have `MainActivity`,`FirstActivity`,`SecondActivity`.

In `MainActivity`, I have 2 *Edittext* name: `Edittext1` and `Edittext2`. Also, I have 1 *button* which will submit the result **SIMULTANEOUSLY** to `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

In `FirstActivity`,there will have 1 *textview* which will get result of `Edittext1` from `MainActivity`. Also it have 1 *button* intent when click will navigate to `SecondActivity`.

The problem: How to get data of `Edittext2` from `MainActivity`?

Comment: can you post the intent code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: can you please tell me from which activity you want to get data of Edittext2 .

Comment: not duplicate because i want to transfer multiple data to different activity. not for the same activity.

Comment: @RishavSingla from MainActivity.

Comment: it **IS** a duplicate because that question is about different activity.

Comment: why dont you pass all data to one activity?

Comment: Dont make things complex always try things to do in a simple way.

Comment: @MuhammadZawawi See my below answer, to get data of EditText2 from MainActivity. It will help you. Thanks!

Comment: @RishavSingla he want to go from main activity to first activity and then second activity but wants data of main activity on second activity

Comment: @AliAhmed i will update my answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code inside MainActivity.java**

```
mainActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Editext1", editText1.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Editext2", editText2.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Code inside First Activity.java**

```
firstActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("Editext2Data", getIntent().getStringExtra("Edittext2"););
         startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Update:**

As you want to directly access main activity data. you can use `static` variable to store edittext data and get that data any where (Not a good approach)

**in main activity intialize it globally**

```
public static String editext2_data = "";
```

**Save data inside it on button click**

```
mainActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {  
         editext2_data = editText2.getText().toString();

        //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("Editext1", editText1.getText().toString());
        //intent.putExtra("Editext2", editText2.getText().toString());
        //startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**From Second Activity Access static variable of MainActivity as**

```
String data = MainActivity.editext2_data;
```

Comment: I think your answer is legit about static which we can use  same data for different activity. I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: yeah. You can access that static variable on any activity you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass both edittext1 and edittext2 data from MainActivity to Firstactivity using intent.putExtras() then from firstactivity you should pass data of edititext2 that you received from Mainactivity to SecondActivity on button click

Comment: is there any technique that i can get from MainActivity? From the Main Activity it will send data edittext1 to FirstActivity then data of edittext2 to Second Activity.

Comment: I don't think so because once you will leave mainactivity you need both edittext data and mainactivity is not going directly to secondactivity that's why you need to pass both values to firstactivity and then from firstactivity you can pass second value to secondactivity

Answer (score 0):

**In MainActivity**

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Editext2", editText2.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**In FirstActivity:**

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("Editext2");
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Editext2Data",data);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

**In SecondActvity:**

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("Editext2Data");
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use of Bundles to pass data from one activity to another activity ..

Just learn about bundles in android ...!!